# Validating username or email in the same text field

Tags: html, css, validation

I want to validate the `<input>` element of a form to check for username or email. The validation should be done for the same textbox

```
<input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Enter username or email">
```

it would be easier if done with pattern attribute in the input tag itself. Because I want to program the validation message using jscript.

Comment: You can use a very lightweight script I've build for this: [validator](https://github.com/yairEO/validator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function validate(field) {
    // var field = document.getElementById('text1').value;

    // CHeck if email
    if (/\@/.test(field)) {
        // Validate email address
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(field)) {
            return (true)
        }
        console.log("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        return (false)
    } else {
        // Validate username
        var error = "";
        var stripped = field.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');

        if (stripped == "") {
            alert("You didn't enter a phone number.");
            error = "You didn't enter a phone number.";
        } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
            phone = "";
            error = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
            alert("illegal characters.");
        } else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) {
            alert("wrong length");
            phone = "";
            error = "The phone number is the wrong length. Make sure you included an area code.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or you want something like this

```
<input id="text1" type="text" placeholder="Enter username or email">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
<script>
    function validate() {
        var field = document.getElementById('text1').value;

        // CHeck if email
        if (/\@/.test(field)) {
            // Validate email address
        }
        else {
            // Validate username
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. But i dont want my form to be validated on button press. i want it to be validated automatically as when we use patterns. Since i am using the default pop up message to display error
http://s33.postimg.org/7tuajglun/Untitled.png

Comment: <input type="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" placeholder="email"> 

like i am using this tag just for email